# QSqlDatabase ODBC query speed

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, qt4

I use `QSqlDatabase` to connect to remote `MSSQL Server`, but it seem the speed very slow. With a same query (the result is about 20 rows), i tried in `MSSQL Management 2008` take about 1s but in my application (use `QSqlDatabase`) it take nearly 8s, Anybody explain me why this happen?

Comment: How do you measure that in the two cases?

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev: In my application i use this code: http://pastebin.com/s5zLkRUy and then display the model to the tableview. The time when i start query to the time my application display data is about 8 seconds or more, and the same to MSSQL management, when start queries to data displayed

Comment: I have figured out that the data not send back to my application in `querry.exec()` yet, but in `querry.next()`, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting setForward(true) and preparing your SQL statements drastically improves performance of SELECT based SQL queries. If setForward(true) is not called, Qt will attempt to loop through the entire result set while querying the database which causes slow downs.